# Showing the ProgressDialog while opening the Website

Tags: android, web, progressdialog

I have to open a website say Facebook page, twitter page and You Tube page in order to share my post there. Now when I click to the item Facebook , it gets redirected to FB to share and same for Twitter and YouTube.

I have to show them in my WebView and all this is done perfectly.

What I want is to show the Progress Dialog after clicking on the Item till it gets redirected to the FB , Twitter or YouTube.

I don know how to show the Progress Bar for redirecting to the Main Website.
Can anyone Please help me put Here.

Thanks,
David Brown

Comment: Here is detailed tutorial: [**Android - Load WebView with ProgressBar**](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-load-webview-with-progressbar/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the Twitter Page Contains the DOM data so you need to do the Following:

```
webViewFollowOn.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

I hope it will Help You...:)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class WebviewcontrollerWebClient extends WebViewClient {


    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
         _dialog =ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Please wait...");
         _dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
         _dialog.setCancelable(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        if(_dialog!=null)
            _dialog.dismiss();

    }
```